# Get the text of a description in an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My goal is to send a message in 2 text channels.
Instead of copying/pasting the same message, I would like to be able to get the description of the first embed and then put it in the following ones.

I tried to get the text of the description of the first embed via `maintenanceEmbed.description` but it sends me back `undefined`

```
    async execute(interaction, client) {
      await interaction.deferReply({ fetchReply: true, ephemeral: true });
      const { options } = interaction;
      const commentaire = options.getString("commentaire");

      const statutChannel = client.channels.cache.get(process.env.statutmc);
      const chatChannel = client.channels.cache.get(process.env.chatmc);

      if (interaction.options.getString('statut') === 'maintenance') {
        const attachmentImage = new AttachmentBuilder("./src/database/img/info.png");
        const maintenanceEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setColor("#FAA619")
          .setAuthor({ name: "Maintenance", iconURL: "attachment://info.png" })
          .setDescription(`Le serveur fermera ces portes dans quelques instants pour cause de maintenance.\n ${commentaire}`);
        await statutChannel.send({ files: [attachmentImage], embeds: [maintenanceEmbed] });

        await chatChannel.send({ content: `>>>  ${maintenanceEmbed.description}`});
      };
      if (interaction.options.getString('statut') === 'arret') {
  
      };
      if (interaction.options.getString('statut') === 'actif') {
  
      };

      const gifSucess = new AttachmentBuilder("./src/database/img/tada.gif");
      const confirmationEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor("#43B17E")
        .setAuthor({ name: "Effectuée avec succès !", iconURL: "attachment://tada.gif" })
      return interaction.editReply({ files: [gifSucess], embeds: [confirmationEmbed], ephemeral: true });
  },
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
exampleEmbed.description
```

to this

```
exampleEmbed.data.description
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set Description for both of them at once:

```js
const text = 'Hello World!'
embed1.setDescription(text)
embed2.setDescription(text)
```

Comment: Indeed, I could also do that, but I rather wanted to take the description of the first embed. But thank you for your message!